# Update Mysql filtrando por data vencida com tolerância de x Dias

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Preciso fazer um update só nos registros que estão vencidos e adicionando uma tolerância de x dias 
Exemplo
               Tolerância de **5** dias
               Hoje é     = **11/10/2016**

id= 1   vencimento = 10/10/2016  // só realizar o update se hoje fosse dia 15

id= 2   vencimento = 06/10/2016  // realizar update

id= 3   vencimento = 10/10/2016  // só realizar o update se hoje fosse dia 15

id= 4   vencimento = 10/10/2016  // só realizar o update se hoje fosse dia 15

Aqui está meu código mais não esta funcionando direito a regra

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE finan SET status='Vencido' WHERE status = 'Em Aberto' AND vencimento < CURDATE() + INTERVAL '$tolerencia' DAY ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu exemplo você está colocando a tolerância na data atual e não na data de vencimento. O update ficaria assim na data correta:

```
UPDATE finan 
   SET status = 'Vencido' 
 WHERE status = 'Em Aberto' 
   AND CURDATE() > vencimento + INTERVAL'$tolerencia' day
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta dessa forma, assumindo que a coluna vencimento seja do tipo "date" ou "datetime"

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE finan SET status='Vencido' WHERE status = 'Em Aberto' AND vencimento + INTERVAL '$tolerencia' DAY < NOW()") or die(mysql_error());
```